# Check if program with specific version is installed

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, installed-applications

I'm trying to create a very simple script which would check if the a specific program is installed and if so return the version number for that program.

I've been able to get to the point where I'm running the script and able to return a binary value if a program is installed or not but not sure how to return the version number for that installed program.

What I will post will be just what I'm doing to return if program is installed, and need help in then attaining the version number.

```
function Check_Program_Installed {
    $my_check = Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* |
                Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, InstallDate |
                Format-Table -AutoSize |
                Out-String

    # Check if Google Chrome is installed
    $my_check -Match "Google Chrome"
}

Check_Program_Installed
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want that function to look for a specific installed program instead of returning a (table) formatted string, then you could simply do:

```
function Check_Program_Installed {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        $Name
    )
    $app = Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*" | 
                Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -match $Name } | 
                Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, InstallDate, Version
    if ($app) {
        return $app.DisplayVersion
    }
}

Check_Program_Installed "Google Chrome"
```

This will return `$null` when not found, or the version as string like `70.0.3538.67`

Comment: This works great on the local computer how would run this on a remote computer?

Answer (score 5):

Instead of doing the match after formatting the table, you could add a where to select the result you need beforehand and then obtain the `DisplayVersion` directly from that object.  You could clean this up more to do exactly what you need, but here is your code modified to retrieve and display the number if the application is found.  Try switching to a bad name to see the `else` result:

```
function Get-ApplicationVersion {

    $applicationName = "Google Chrome"

    $my_check = Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, InstallDate | Where -Property DisplayName -Match $applicationName

    $versionNumber = $my_check.DisplayVersion

    if ($my_check) {
        $versionNumber
    }
    else {
        write-warning "Application not found"
    }

}

Get-ApplicationVersion
```

**EDITED:** Renamed function name from `Check_Program_Installed` to use PS common verb `Get`, per suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

```
function Get-InstalledProgram {
    Param (
        $ProgramName
    )

    $UninstallKeys = Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* 

    if ( $ProgramName )
    {
        $UninstallKeys | Where-Object -Property DisplayName -Match -Value $ProgramName | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, InstallDate
    }
    else
    {
        $UninstallKeys | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, InstallDate
    }
}
```

If you wanted to see all the programs, then you don't have to add a parameter. Just pipe its output to `Format-Table`. Format-Table does some weird just where the items are no longer the objects you're expecting, but table objects. Here is how I would handle that:

```
Get-InstalledProgram | Format-Table -Autosize
```

If you want to search for a program, add a parameter. You'll see above I added a parameter for ProgramName. It will match this term to the registry key's DisplayName.

```
PS C:\> Get-InstalledProgram -ProgramName Java

DisplayName       DisplayVersion InstallDate
-----------       -------------- -----------
Java 8 Update 181 8.0.1810.25    20180725   
Java Auto Updater 2.8.181.13     20180925
```

If you wanted to just get the version, I would recommend just piping your output to `Select-Object -ExpandProperty DisplayVersion`

```
PS C:\> Get-InstalledProgram -ProgramName 'Java 8' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DisplayVersion
8.0.1810.25
```

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr**

In **Windows PowerShell**<sup>[1]</sup> **v5.1+**, use the following (searches among *both* 32-bit and 64-bit installed programs, as shown in Control Panel):

```sh
Get-Package -ProviderName Programs -IncludeWindowsInstaller '*Google Chrome*' |
  ForEach-Object Version
```

<sup>Note: The 32-bit-only `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` registry key may have more specific entries than what Control Panel shows - I'm unclear on why, but perhaps the composite view in Control Panel is sufficient.</sup>

Applied to your example:

```sh
PS> (Get-Package -ProviderName Programs -IncludeWindowsInstaller '*Google Chrome*').Version
70.0.3538.67
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

Since you're checking the `Wow6432Node` registry key branch specifically, **you're checking installed *32-bit* programs only**.

As such, a better name for your function would be `Check_32BitProgram_Installed` or, more in line with with the function's intent, using an [approved PowerShell verb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/approved-verbs-for-windows-powershell-commands), `Get-32BitProgramVersion`.

Alternatively, name, the function `Get-ProgramVersion` and look in *both* the 32-bit and 64-bit locations and process the results as shown in [Theo's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52856925/45375) and [Kevin M. Lapio's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52856963/45375) and [Shawn Esterman's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52856918/45375) helpful answers:

```sh
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*,
                 HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*
```

---

In line with the generic title of your question, the above is a solution that essentially searches the list of installed applications you would see in Control Panel > Programs > Programs and Features (`appwiz.cpl`), which covers both 32-bit and 64-bit applications:

**Windows PowerShell v5.1** comes with the **`PackageManagement` module** and a **`Programs` package provider**<sup>[1]</sup> that allows inspecting installed programs via the `Get-Package` cmdlet; in PSv3 and PSv4, it is possible to [manually install it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/gallery/installing-psget).

To list installed programs (shown with abridged sample output):

```sh
PS> Get-Package -ProviderName Programs -IncludeWindowsInstaller

Name                           Version          Source                           ProviderName                                                                  
----                           -------          ------                           ------------                                                                  
Git version 2.18.0             2.18.0                                            Programs                                                                      
Microsoft Azure Compute Emu... 2.9.8699.20                                       Programs                                                                      
Microsoft Azure Authoring T... 2.9.8699.20                                       Programs                                                                      
# ...
```

The output objects are of type `[Microsoft.PackageManagement.Packaging.SoftwareIdentity]`, which have `.Name` and `.Version` properties, which enables the solutions above.

The `Programs` package provider supports two dynamic options (options specific to that provider):

- `-IncludeWindowsInstaller` is needed to make the list of programs reported match what Control Panel shows.
- `-IncludeSystemComponent`, by contrast, reports components that do *not* show in Control Panel.

---

[1] Unfortunately, the underlying `Programs` package provider is ***not* available in PowerShell *Core* on Windows** as of v7.0 - and I'm unclear on whether that is a not-yet situation or whether it will never be - see [GitHub issue #13225](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/13225).